# SEToolkit cloned website can be viewed over internet, but does not harvest credentials

Tags: penetration-test, phishing, kali-linux

I've been working with SEToolkit's website cloner/credential harvester. Everything works fine locally: The clone opens on the victim pc, victim inputs credentials, after submitting the victim is redirected to the real page and the credentials are stored in a text file.

However, when I port forward port 80 for the private IP of the Apache server, the website can be viewed but it hangs once the user submits the credentials. The credentials are never stored and the user is never redirected to the real page.

I was wondering if anyone here has encountered this issue as I have not seen this question come up through google searches. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Although you are using SET, this is looking like a network issue and not a security issue. Check firewalls, server configs, and get a packet capture on the remote client to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the HTML source, where is the form posting to? My guess is that it's configured for an internal address, which would cause your issue, since nobody else will be able to reach it by its internal address. Change the action= attribute in the form tag to be the public facing IP address.

Comment: That was the exact solution to the problem. Thank you for your help.